# Spring boot how to append multiple properties to single value?

Tags: spring-boot, properties

I have multiple properties in my `application.properties` file

```
prop.a=A
prop.b=B
prop.c=C
// and more
```

Now i have to add the property A to the rest of them. I am doing this like following

```
    @Value("${prop.a}")
    private String a;

    @Value("${prop.b}")
    private String b;
    b = new StringBuffer(b).append(a).toString();
```

I have to individually append each string. Can i do this in the annotation? like `@Value("${prop.b}" + "${prop.a}")` ?

Comment: You can use SpEL.

Comment: @BoristheSpider can you please show example?

Comment: try `#{${prop.a} + ${prop.b}}`

Comment: getting this error   https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/p9vSDGWWcF/

Comment: Is it not OK for you if you do this in `application.properties` itself? Like `prop.b=${prop.a}B`?

Comment: @SreeKumar Not exactly. I will need prop.b separately too. I want to keep the properties atomic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to do this programmatically, you have to do this:

```
@Value( "${prop.a}${prop.b}" )
private String b;
```

You can, however, achieve this in `application.properties` itself this way:

```
prop.a=A
prop.b=${prop.a}B
prop.c=${prop.a}C
```

(Please note that wherever your example says `prob.*`,I have changed to `prop.*`.)

Comment: Sorry prob was a typo, question updated